# Route before getting executed after the route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my routes.php I have the following group:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'checkSomething', 'prefix' => '{lang}'), function() {
echo "1";
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@home'));
});
```

And the filter attached to it:

```
Route::filter('checkSomething', function(){
echo "2";
    if(!somethingNotRight($something)){
        return Redirect::route('index', array()));
    }
});
```

My question is, why is the route inside the route group getting called first, and after that the filter? If I execute this code, I get the following result:

> 21

But what I want is:

> 12

Comment: did you try `Controller::beforeFilter()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple isn't it? You are aplying your filter BEFORE the app hits the controller of the route, if you want to apply filter after just change:

```html
Route::group(array('after' => 'checkSomething', 'prefix' => '{lang}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the `Route::group` closure isn't called at the moment the route is executed. It's called very early to **register** all the routes. The filter is working correctly, but to test that you'd need to put the echo *inside the controller*

Comment: But lets say I have a route with a ->where() statement. That ->where() is dependent on a Session variable which is set in the filter. So before calling the controller method, I need something from the filter. How would I do that?

Comment: You wouldn't. The where statement needs to be "ready" when the routes file is loaded. Laravel searches for a matching route (using the URI and where conditions) and only after that the filter is run.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to do but you could just retrieve the session value right inside `routes.php`

Comment: Well, my routes are dependent on translation strings. So for example: I want something like ->where(array('location' => trans('general.location')) But for that I need to App::setLocale() first. I can just set the locale in the routes.php file, but that isn't very clean.

Comment: You could do it in `App::before`